# AmazonS3 console: An unexpected error occurred

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created my AWS account, and I'm trying to manually create a bucket through the console. But all the action buttons are disabled, and it shows `An unexpected error occurred` as in the image below. Has anyone experienced this? What could be the possible cause of this?

[image: aws error]

Comment: I would suggest refresh or force refresh. Does it still happen?

Comment: If the AWS Account is very new, strange things can happen while the account is setup. I suggest you wait 24-48 hours and try again. You could also try using a different browser, and even look in the browser's Developer Console to see whether any useful information is provided.

Comment: @jarmod I have force refreshed and it's still not working.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I've tried using firefox and it turns out the project manager did not complete signup. Firefox displays that, but chrome doesn't. Thanks for the tip.